# Call method inside that method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecma

Consider this:

```js
class ConnectUser {
    connect = () => {
        axios.get('URL').catch(err => {
            // CAN I CALL `connect` METHOD AGAIN?!
            // this.connect();
        });
    }
}
```

My code has a method and can connect or refuse to connect to some resources. If an exception happens can I call it again to strive for connecting?

Comment: @David784 It's the other way round, actually. An arrow function will always have the instance as the `this` value, while an ordinary method (that should be written `connect() {…}`, not `connect = function() {…}`) only has the correct `this` value if it's called on the instance

Comment: Don't forget to `return` the result of the recursive call from the `catch` callback to make proper use of promise chaining! And always limit your attempts to a maximum number of retries, and add exponential backoff.

Comment: @David784 You're wrong David. As Bergi said arrow function always has the instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. But if this is something you want to generalize on your app, consider using an axios [plugin that automatically retries](https://github.com/softonic/axios-retry) and only fails after the amount of retries you specify.
You can call just connect function again if you define it as a separate function on the scope instead of a class method. But if you really need to call using this, save the proper this reference in the outer closure like this:

```
connect = () => {
      const self = this 
        axios.get('URL').catch(err => {
            self.connect();
        });
    }
```

Then use self instead

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to Danielo's answer - if you want `this` inside `connect` to refer to the class instance, you can simply define `connect` as a method of the class, i.e.

```
class ConnectUser {
    connect() {
        axios.get('URL').catch(err => {
            return this.connect();
        });
    }
}
```